# Can Grover's algorithm be used to search in a real database?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

I'd like to start with saying sorry if my question makes no sense as I'm a physics student, but only in third year.

I've discovered Grover's algorithm, but what I'm not sure of is if it could be used as a real database or if it's for searching something like an array? For example if you had a database column of strings 8-chars long could you use Grover's algorithm to search for a match (let's say x='quantumc')?

Then my follow up question is would you need 64 logical qubits to make this calculation? (8 binary bits x 8 characters)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This other post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5696/how-is-the-grover-algorithm-applied-to-a-database) may help you

Comment: @epelaaez very interesting post, thanks :)

Comment: see also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2372/55 and links therein

Answer (score 3):

Many many people refer to Grover's algorithm as a "database search" but this is not a very good description of what it does.  It's actually an algorithm that searches for a solution that makes an oracle function return True, where an oracle function is a function that, given an input, outputs whether or not the input is the solution to a problem you want to solve. Grover&s algorithm is much closer to a boolean-sat solver in that sense. It is not a practical way to build a database.  I hope your confusion has been solved!

Comment: ah thanks! who would have thought this stuff would be confusing, eh

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that link, if you know some programming/python, you might want to check the Qiskit textbook entry for Grover's algorithm. Also not that a  database is an organized collection of structured information. So when we say "search in database" we're not necessarily saying search in some oracle/mysql database, but if needed, the algorithm can be implemented to search in a database with some key-value association.

> could you use Grover's algorithm to search for a match (let's say x='quantumc')?

Yes you can. It's done at the oracle step, the oracle will simply answer "yes it's the element we want" or "no it's not".

> Then my follow up question is would you need 64 logical qubits to make this calculation? (8 binary bits x 8 characters)
> The reasoning is not accurate... to answer your question I will give an example. Given an array that has 42 elements, how many bits do I need in order to express the index when I find the value I am looking for?  to express the indices up to 42 you need 6 bits. So you need 6 qubits.

You can convince yourself with an example.
watch this video, or simply copy the implementation from the qiskit textbook

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RPFWZj7Jm0&ab_channel=Qiskit

Try to run the code on a real quantum machine from IBM with a limited number of qubits or even using the simulator

Or you can use this notebook (from Qiskit summer school lab2):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/plo3lcq0vb0jipo/QSS2020-lab2.ipynb?dl=0

Further reading:
[https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~imarkov/pubs/jour/cise05-grov.pdf](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Eimarkov/pubs/jour/cise05-grov.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it. This might be something I can add to my resume too haha :)